# Marvin pouring constant stream of QCDataUploader errors on Android device

Tags: bug, android-app

My [Nexus 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7_%282013%29) is pouring out a constant stream of this:

```
05-17 12:12:01.986: E/q.QCDataUploader(21261): Could not upload events
05-17 12:12:01.986: E/q.QCDataUploader(21261): Events not sent to server. Response code: 408
05-17 12:12:01.986: E/q.QCDataManager(21261): Failed to upload 200 events
05-17 12:12:02.173: E/q.QCDataUploader(21261): Could not upload events
05-17 12:12:02.174: E/q.QCDataUploader(21261): Events not sent to server. Response code: 408
05-17 12:12:02.174: E/q.QCDataManager(21261): Failed to upload 200 events
05-17 12:12:02.363: E/q.QCDataUploader(21261): Could not upload events
05-17 12:12:02.364: E/q.QCDataUploader(21261): Events not sent to server. Response code: 408
05-17 12:12:02.364: E/q.QCDataManager(21261): Failed to upload 200 events
05-17 12:12:02.574: E/q.QCDataUploader(21261): Could not upload events
05-17 12:12:02.574: E/q.QCDataUploader(21261): Events not sent to server. Response code: 408
05-17 12:12:02.574: E/q.QCDataManager(21261): Failed to upload 200 events
05-17 12:12:02.766: E/q.QCDataUploader(21261): Could not upload events
05-17 12:12:02.766: E/q.QCDataUploader(21261): Events not sent to server. Response code: 408
05-17 12:12:02.766: E/q.QCDataManager(21261): Failed to upload 200 events
05-17 12:12:02.952: E/q.QCDataUploader(21261): Could not upload events
05-17 12:12:02.952: E/q.QCDataUploader(21261): Events not sent to server. Response code: 408
05-17 12:12:02.952: E/q.QCDataManager(21261): Failed to upload 200 events
05-17 12:12:03.140: E/q.QCDataUploader(21261): Could not upload events
```

It doesn't stop.

Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/16698105/852795 I identified PID 21261 as com.stackexchange.marvin. Marvin is apparently the [Paranoid Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_%28character%29). From a search I think QCDataUploader is from Quantcast, which makes me suppose that my device is trying (but failing) to upload data to them.

I recently installed the [Stack Exchange app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) on my device, so now I'm guessing that this app is trying to upload data to Quantcast. Perhaps that's how we get https://www.quantcast.com/app/Stack_Exchange/c1rF4kxgLUzNc-tv0q7g1v8zjc5a1j#trafficCard. Confirmed! When I halt the Stack Exchange app the errors stop.

Also, I noticed that the Wi-Fi on the device was off. Relauching the Stack Exchange app starts up the errors again, but they stop when I enable Wi-Fi.

I think I solved the mystery while composing the question, and this looks like a bug report, so I'm posting in meta. Can someone suggest to Marvin to stop trying to upload data to Quantcast when Wi-Fi is disabled?

Comment: **This is on-topic here**. It's about the SE Android app; it's not a programming question. Don't close it.

Comment: It really did look like your typical drive by off topic question.  Edited the title  to make it clearer this is about the SO app

Comment: I thought calling the app "Mavin" was cuter, but I get it.

Comment: How long until somebody comes along and removes "Stack Overflow Android app" for being a "tag in the title"? /cc @Will

Comment: @BoltClock Well, actually, now that everybody knows, and the question isn't at risk of being downvoted/close-voted, let's have some fun with the title

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Could be titled: "Marvin complaining too much"

Comment: @Undo Actually, according to [the tag summary](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-app/info), it's off-topic: "Questions about the Android app should be asked on Meta Stack Exchange."

Comment: @IMSoP Should be asked there, yes, but that doesn't make it off-topic on the per-site metas. Traditionally, per-site metas can be used as a substitute for mSE.

Comment: @Undo Meh, if you say so. To me, a tag wiki consisting only of a pointer to ask on another site seems like a pretty clear flag of "this is off topic here".